# search for option in dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find if a option is in the dropdown and use its value.
this is NOT when selected. I purely want to scan the list for `Procedures` and get the value from it.

```
<select class="FormDropDown " id="procedure-category-fld" name="procedure-category-fld">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="4">Cause</option>
    <option value="5">Disorder</option>
    <option value="6">Procedure</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the `option` elements from within the `select` you have and extract their value/text using jquery:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#procedure-category-fld option').each(function(i, el) {
    console.log($(el).val(), $(el).text());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="FormDropDown " id="procedure-category-fld" name="procedure-category-fld">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="4">Cause</option>
    <option value="5">Disorder</option>
    <option value="6">Procedure</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```js
var value = $('#procedure-category-fld option').filter(function (idx, ele) {
    return ele.textContent == "Procedure";
}).val();

console.log(value);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select class="FormDropDown " id="procedure-category-fld" name="procedure-category-fld">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="4">Cause</option>
    <option value="5">Disorder</option>
    <option value="6">Procedure</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a great alternative, but Dekel was first.

Comment: Thanks @morne appreciate it :)